# KMDF MmCopyVirtualMemory Undefined

Tags: kmdf

Hello and my problem today is I was trying out a new/old method of writing memory with a system files(.sys) after watching Zer0Mem0ry's video on the subject. But I tried to copy but came with the error :

```
 Error C4013 'MmCopyVirtualMemory' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

Even after having done everything. So I was wondering if I had to define this function or importation would be enough. Any help would be amazing! 
My Code(driver.c)

https://pastebin.com/AfBUGFCh

Couldn't paste code for some reason.

```
#include "driver.h"
#include <ntddk.h>
#include "driver.tmh"
#pragma comment(lib, "Ntoskrnl.lib")

#ifdef ALLOC_PRAGMA
#pragma alloc_text (INIT, DriverEntry)
#pragma alloc_text (PAGE, CallOfDutySysFileEvtDeviceAdd)
#pragma alloc_text (PAGE, CallOfDutySysFileEvtDriverContextCleanup)
#endif

NTSTATUS KeReadProcessMemory(PEPROCESS Process, PVOID SourceAddress, PVOID TargetAddress, SIZE_T Size)
{
    PEPROCESS SourceProcess = Process;
    PEPROCESS TargetProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    SIZE_T Result;
    if (NT_SUCCESS(MmCopyVirtualMemory(SourceProcess, SourceAddress, TargetProcess, TargetAddress, Size, KernelMode, &Result)))
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    else
        return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
}
NTSTATUS KeWriteProcessMemory(PEPROCESS Process, PVOID SourceAddress, PVOID TargetAddress, SIZE_T Size)
{
    PEPROCESS SourceProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    PEPROCESS TargetProcess = Process;
    SIZE_T Result;

    if (NT_SUCCESS(MmCopyVirtualMemory(SourceProcess, SourceAddress, TargetProcess, TargetAddress, Size, KernelMode, &Result)))
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    else
        return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;

}

NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attributes;
    WPP_INIT_TRACING(DriverObject, RegistryPath);
    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Entry");
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT(&attributes);
    attributes.EvtCleanupCallback = CallOfDutySysFileEvtDriverContextCleanup;

    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config,
                           CallOfDutySysFileEvtDeviceAdd
                           );

    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject,
                             RegistryPath,
                             &attributes,
                             &config,
                             WDF_NO_HANDLE
                             );

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, TRACE_DRIVER, "WdfDriverCreate failed %!STATUS!", status);
        WPP_CLEANUP(DriverObject);
        return status;
    }

    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Exit");



    return status;
}

NTSTATUS
CallOfDutySysFileEvtDeviceAdd(
    _In_    WDFDRIVER       Driver,
    _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    PAGED_CODE();

    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Entry");

    status = CallOfDutySysFileCreateDevice(DeviceInit);

    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Exit");

    return status;
}

VOID
CallOfDutySysFileEvtDriverContextCleanup(
    _In_ WDFOBJECT DriverObject
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);

    PAGED_CODE();

    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Entry");

    WPP_CLEANUP(WdfDriverWdmGetDriverObject((WDFDRIVER)DriverObject));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it exists in another file called [ReadWrite.c](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/KernelReadWriteMemory/blob/master/ReadWrite.c) you can find in the Zer0Mem0ry's github

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't seem to want us to use this function, you just need to add them in front of your code：
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) NTSTATUS NTAPI MmCopyVirtualMemory
(
PEPROCESS SourceProcess,
PVOID SourceAddress,
PEPROCESS TargetProcess,
PVOID TargetAddress,
SIZE_T BufferSize,
KPROCESSOR_MODE PreviousMode,
PSIZE_T ReturnSize
);